# Total work hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
log_date    log_time           emp_id    emp_name          log_action       
2013-06-16  08:48:48.0000000    30170   Sarah John          1
2013-06-16  16:48:48.0000000    30170   Sarah John          4
2013-06-15  07:18:48.0000000    30160   Paula Fred          1
2013-06-15  16:38:48.0000000    30160   Paula Fred          4
```

I have a log table with the above information. I have a query to calculate the daily work hours for each employee and store them in a decimal field in another. The problem is the minutes are off and if an employee punchin/punchout more than once in the same day it adds the hours. I would like it to only account for the the first good  punchin/punchout.

```
Select DISTINCT emp_id,log_date,SUM(datediff(Minute,stm, etm))/60.0
  as wrk_hrs from
(
    SELECT
        emp_id, log_date,
        log_time as etm,
        (
            SELECT top 1 log_time
            FROM tblLogs
            WHERE log_action = '1' and log_time <= a.log_time and emp_id=a.emp_id and a.log_date=log_date order by log_time desc
        ) as stm
    FROM tblLogs as a
    WHERE log_action = '4'
)as a
where stm is not null
group by log_date,emp_id,a.stm,a.etm;
```

Is there a more accurate way to calculate the hours and minutes and store them for further calculations. I Need over time and total weekly hours for a report.

Comment: What do you mean by "more accurate"?

Comment: I mean closer the actual hours and minutes. I noticed in an instance where I should have gotten 7 hours and 10 minutes I get 7.1666. I know its not much but I have to sum the total hours per week and its setting the total way off.

Comment: What are the data types of the date and time fields?

Comment: Date is Date datatype time is a time datatype

Comment: @user2382789 - 10 minutes **are** 1/6 == 0.166 of an hour.

Comment: 7.1666 hours = 7 hours 10 minutes.

Comment: Oh I see I was hoping to get the actual minutes and not the fraction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT StartLog.emp_id, StartLog.log_date,  SUM(datediff(Minute,stm, etm))/60.0
FROM (
    SELECT emp_id, log_date, MIN(log_time) AS stm 
    FROM tblLogs
    WHERE log_action = '1'
    GROUP BY emp_id, log_date
    ) AS StartLog
INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT emp_id, log_date, MIN(log_time) AS etm 
        FROM tblLogs
        WHERE log_action = '4'
        GROUP BY emp_id, log_date
    ) AS EndLog
    ON StartLog.emp_id = EndLog.emp_id AND StartLog.log_date = EndLog.log_date
```

Comment: the error what that the position of the WHERE clauses were after the GROUP, I corrected the query

Comment: I am getting Ambiguous column name 'emp_id' and 'log_date'. I am relatively new to mssql

Comment: my bad... I did a quick and dirty join for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want the first entry per employee-day-action:

```
SELECT
  [log_date],
  [emp_id],
  [emp_name],
  [1] AS [first_log_in],
  [4] AS [first_log_out],
  DATEDIFF(minute,[1],[4])/60.0 AS [hours]
FROM @tblLogs
PIVOT(MIN(log_time) FOR log_action IN ([1],[4])) p
```

This assumes your log data is in good shape. If you need to check for punchout-before-punchin or multiple punchins before punchout, that's a whole different question.

Comment: If a person punches in multiple times only the first punch is be used

Answer (score 0):

If you want more accuracy, switch to seconds:

```
Select emp_id,log_date,SUM(datediff(second,stm, etm))/3600.0
  as wrk_hrs from
(
    SELECT
        emp_id, log_date,
        log_time as etm,
        (
            SELECT top 1 log_time
            FROM tblLogs
            WHERE log_action = '1' and log_time <= a.log_time and emp_id=a.emp_id and a.log_date=log_date order by log_time desc
        ) as stm
    FROM tblLogs as a
    WHERE log_action = '4'
)as a
where stm is not null
group by log_date,emp_id,a.stm,a.etm;
```

Note:  `distinct` is generally totally redundant when using `group by`.